# Stuck while setting List Item for an one of setter method

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to set for the field

```
// takes List<JsonHistory> as argument
sprintdata.setJsonHistory()

public List<JsonHistory> getJsonHistory() {
    return jsonHistory;
}

public void setJsonHistory(List<JsonHistory> jsonHistory) {
    this.jsonHistory= jsonHistory;
}
```

Below is the full impl which I tried, but not able to set the list item in above setter methods.I am missing something, can you guys please suggest me for my mistake.

```
json = jsonHistory(settings.getView(),sprint.getId(),settings.getCredentials(),settings.getBaseUrl());

    JsonHistory jsonHistory = new JsonHistory();

    jsonHistory.setCompleted(SomeUtil.getVelocity(json, sprint.getId(), "completedSum"));
    jsonHistory.setAllEstimate(SomeUtil.getVelocity(json, sprint.getId(), "allEstimateSum"));

    List<JsonHistory> jsonHistoryList = new ArrayList<JsonHistory>();
    sampleData.getJsonHistory().add(jsonHistory);
    jsonHistoryList.add(jsonHistory);

    sampleData.setJsonHistory(jsonHistoryList)
```

I apologize for my mistake.

Comment: What is the problem exactly..? what variable are you trying to set and where?

Comment: You need to share more code. definition of `setBurDownHistory()`

Comment: I updated The code

Comment: `sampleData.setJsonHistory(jsonHistoryList)` is where you are getting the error?  What is `sprintdata` and `sampleData` typeof

Comment: Is `sampleData` an object of the class where `List<JsonHistory> jsonHistory` is the member??

Comment: yes @Shubhendu Pramanik

Comment: (a) you haven't explained what the problem is - "not able to set the list item" is not a problem statement. Do you have a compilation error? A runtime error? What is the error message? etc. (b) Try to create a [mcve].

Comment: Hi guys thanks for response! Now Its working fine after debugging couple of times, not sure what was the issue.